# How Google Indexer should only index published pages

Tags: publish, google, noindex

In my wordpress site I have different posts and pages. I want that google only index those pages which are published. The 'DRAFT' pages should not be indexed by google.

What is the best way to achieve this. There is an API from google called GOOGLE INDEXING API which perform this task but there is no wordpress plugin available.

Can any wordpress expert help in this regard?

Thanks

Comment: Google won’t index draft pages. It can’t access them. Is this even a problem you’ve experienced?

Comment: I have a draft page, after 1 day I have make it published. After publishing it should be indexed by google. Then again after 1 month I have changed its status to Draft. In that case that page should be deleted from google index. Hope you understand now.